# Do any laptops other than Macbooks have multi-touch?

Tags: laptop

In particular, how well does the multi-touch work (ie. is it laggy or inaccurate) and how many gestures are supported?

Comment: I don't think I've ever come across one that doesn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most laptops have [Synaptics](http://www.synaptics.com/solutions/products/touchpad) touchpads, which have had multitouch for a few years now (two finger I think), and gestures for many more years than that.

Comment: Three-finger, at least.

Comment: @Ignacio: Oh, okay.  I have not had a laptop with a touchpad since around 2002.  ThinkPad X-series fan.

Comment: Synaptics multi-touch driver settings on my Envy http://i.imgur.com/SI7vo.png

Comment: Are there any competitors to Synaptics?

Comment: +1, thanks a lot for the tip! I was able to get multi-touch on my 2008 Vista laptop by installing Synaptics Scrybe. Cool!

Comment: @Casebash: Alps is the closest, followed by Wacom.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the support in the touchpad, there's also the integration with the OS to be considered. Like: scrolling on a Mac never needs you to first click in the part of the window you want to scroll. (The part to be scrolled does not need focus; [KatMouse](http://ehiti.de/katmouse/) can solve that, for what I've heard. I guess good drivers can achieve the same.)

Also, on a Mac, drag operations allow you to shortly remove your fingers from the touchpad without ending the drag operation yet. So, when you hit the border of the touchpad, you can put your fingers on the other side of the touchpad and continue dragging from there. (Again, I guess good drivers can support that too.)

Answer (score 2):

Laggy: no
Inaccurate: no
These answers are based on my experience.  I have never had a problem with multi-touch, ever.

Any computer can have an Apple multi-touch as Apple sells the touch pad (no Apple's is not integrated into any other laptops I'm aware of).  There are windows drivers available for it (Win7 is multi-touch capable on my MBP)  For a break down of the gestures [go here](http://www.danrodney.com/mac/multitouch.html).

Comment: Why did you link me to the Mac gestures?

Comment: "and how many gestures are supported?"  I thought it might help answer part of the question you asked.

Comment: About time you learn the [top-secret two-spaces trick](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26011/should-the-markdown-renderer-treat-a-single-line-break-as-br) ;-)

Comment: Oh, I get what you were thinking. Nm